# History of the theory on Ideal convergence

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, ideals, math-history, filters

I have mentioned in my recent posts that I'm studying *Ideal-convergence*. So the thing is I am expected to make a small presentation on this topic in two weeks on what I have learnt so far and understood and stuff. And in that presentation I have to first make an introduction to this topic discussing the origins of this theory or say how it first came into existence and so on. So **where can I find the history of this?** Also any advice on how to make this presentation a good one like what theorems to start with after introduction and how to proceed further, are most welcome.

Following are the papers I have read thus far:

$[1]$ Pratulananda Das, Sanjoy Ghosal: *When I-Cauchy nets in complete uniform spaces are I-convergent*, Topology and its Applications,
Volume 158, Issue 13, 15 August 2011, Pages 1529–1533,
[DOI:10.1016/j.topol.2011.05.006](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.topol.2011.05.006)

$[2]$ Pratulananda Das and Ekrem Savas: *On I-convergence of nets in locally solid Riesz spaces*, Filomat 27:1 (2013), 89–94, [DOI:10.2298/FIL1301089D](http://dx.doi.org/10.2298/FIL1301089D)

$[3]$ B. K. Lahiri and Pratulananda Das: *$I$ and $I^*$-Convergence of Nets*, Real Anal. Exchange, Volume 33, Number 2 (2007), 431-442; [projecteuclid](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rae/1229619420).

$[4]$ Pratulananda Das  and Sanjoy Kr. Ghosal: *Some further results on I-Cauchy sequences and condition (AP)*, Comp. Math. Appl., 59 (2010), 2597-2600,
[DOI:10.1016/j.camwa.2010.01.027](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.camwa.2010.01.027).

$[5]$ Ekrem Savas: *$\mathcal I_\lambda$-statistically convergent sequences in topological groups, Acta et Commentationes Universitatis Tartuensis de Mathematica, Vol 18, No 1 (2014), [DOI: 10.12697/ACUTM.2014.18.04](http://dx.doi.org/10.12697/ACUTM.2014.18.04).

$[6]$ Amar Kumar Banerjee, Apurba Banerjee: *[A note on $I$-convergence and $I^{\star}$-convergence of sequences and nets in topological spaces](https://www.emis.de/journals/MV/153/7.html)*, Matematicki Vesnik, Vol. 67, No. 3, pp. 212-221 (2015).

$[7]$ Martin Mačaj, Martin Sleziak: $\mathcal I^{\mathcal K}$-converence, Real Analysis Exchange, 36(1) (2010/2011), 177-194
[arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.2874), [projecteuclid](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rae/1300108092).

$[8]$ Benoy Kumar Lahiri; Pratulananda Das: $\mathcal I$ *and* $\mathcal I^*$-*convergence in topological spaces* , Mathematica Bohemica, Vol. 130 (2005), No. 2, 153–160  [MathBohem](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/134133/MathBohem_130-2005-2_3.pdf)

If this is not fine I'm ready to read study more stuff.

I am very very sorry for I know this not precisely a mathematical question but I did not know where else to go for advice. It is related to mathematics though.

Comment: I will just mention that in the joint paper with Martin Mačaj (item [7] in your list gives arxiv link, here is also [projecteuclid link](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rae/1300108092)) we have tried to give an a brief overview of ideal convergence (or dually filter convergence). It was used by Cartan, Robinson, Bernstein, Katětov and probably many others.

Comment: These posts might also be of the interest: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420538/ultrafilters-when-did-it-start and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19285/how-do-you-axiomatize-topology-via-nets/31443#31443

Comment: Having a list of "this" forces whoever looks at this question to open each paper to know what's inside. How about proper citations?

Comment: @MartinSleziak, it seems you are in a good position to give an accessible answer here :-) I would be curious to see if the *ultralimits* populirized by Terry Tao fit in this framework; see e.g., [this post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/12/07/ultraproducts-as-a-bridge-between-discrete-and-continuous-analysis).

Comment: You may also like http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X07014291